# _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Tags: flutter

I got error "   _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')  " in Flutter in get call, I haven't used any classes, I convert data directly, example data['id']. I'm sending get call from my base provider

```
   Future<List<T>> get([dynamic search]) async {
    var url = "$_baseUrl$_endpoint";

    if (search != null) {
      String queryString = getQueryString(search);
      url = url + "?" + queryString;
    }

    var uri = Uri.parse(url);

    Map<String, String> headers = createHeaders();
    var response = await http!.get(uri, headers: headers);
    if (isValidResponseCode(response)) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      return data.map((x) => fromJson(x)).cast<T>().toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception("Exception... handle this gracefully");
    }
  }
```

This is what I get from api
[JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vacJA.png)

How can I fix this? Please dont remove my post, I tried to find solution for this but I haven't successed. Thank you very much

//UPDATED

```
 Future<T?> get([dynamic search]) async {
    var url = "$_baseUrl$_endpoint";

    if (search != null) {
      String queryString = getQueryString(search);
      url = url + "?" + queryString;
    }

    var uri = Uri.parse(url);

    Map<String, String> headers = createHeaders();
    var response = await http!.get(uri, headers: headers);
    if (isValidResponseCode(response)) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];

      return data;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Exception... handle this gracefully");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide your json response on https://justpaste.it/ or host on https://jsonkeeper.com/

Comment: https://jpst.it/2Vmlm

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
  List data = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

or u can add this

```
     var data = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
     List result=await data.map((x) => fromJson(x)).cast<T>().toList();
     return result
```

Comment: I got this error then NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.

Comment: it's throwing error again...

Comment: I have used (see "updated" above in question) and it works

Comment: @eRes ok good..